# RestKit crash when resuming the app from background

Tags: iphone, json, exception, restkit

I'm using the RestKit framework for my app to server JSON communication. Everything is going well until I hit the home button and try to resume my app. I get an exception_bad_access in this framework method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldDispatchRequest {
if (nil == self.reachabilityObserver || NO == [self.reachabilityObserver isReachabilityDetermined]) {
    return YES;
}

return [self.reachabilityObserver isNetworkReachable];
```

}

In this line: `if (nil == self.reachabilityObserver || NO == [self.reachabilityObserver isReachabilityDetermined]) {`

If I try and reopen my app the second time it loads with no issues-but looses the screen I was on and subsequent information.

Any idea on resolving this?

Thanks, Clinton

Comment: I have also noticed this, but only on one Mac. It seems that on that Mac, there's something up with its handling of https connections. I haven't had time to look into it yet though.

Comment: I have seen a lot of "unrecognized selector sent to instance" crashes from a RestKit app I developed. They all have the isReachabilityDetermined message getting sent to __NSCFInputStream, __NSCFArray, __NSCFSet, and __NSCFType objects. I don't know why that would be. I put in a respondsToSelector check in to try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing it with this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldDispatchRequest {
    if (nil != self.reachabilityObserver && YES == [self.reachabilityObserver isReachabilityDetermined]) {
        return [self.reachabilityObserver isNetworkReachable];
    }
}

return YES;
```